# Conversation, Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am developing an application where I need users to interact with each other using a chat-like system.

To this purpose, I want to create a `Conversation` model. As far as I've been able to read, I am going to use a Many-to-Many relationship.

Having the following models: `Conversation`, `User` and `Message`, I imagined the following tables:

conversations: `id | user1_id | user2_id` - I am not sure if Laravel would understand the user IDs being numbered

messages: `id | message | conversation_id | user_id`

Would this be the right way to do it? And will it work with the `user1_id` and `user2_id` tables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest:

- Many-to-many: User <-> Conversation. A `User` can have many `Conversation`s, a `Conversation` consists of two or more `User`s
- One-to-many: User <-> Message. A `Message` belongs to one `User`. A `User` has many `Message`s
- One-to-many: Message <-> Conversation. A `Message` belongs to one `Conversation`. A `Conversation` has many `Message`s.

This will give you following SQL structure (only attributes interesting for the relationships listed):

```
users: id
messages: id | user_id | conversation_id
conversations: id
conversations_users: conversation_id | user_id
```

Think about conversations like chat rooms, its basically one shared collection of messages between a couple of users.

In Laravel, possible Eloquent models would look like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Conversation');
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Message'); // not as relevant, because these are all messages across conversations
    }
}

class Message extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function conversation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Conversation');
    }
}

class Conversation extends Eloquent
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Message');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}

// Users conversations
$conversations = User::find(1)->conversations;

foreach($conversations as $conversation)
{
    // All members of conversation
    $members = $conversation->users;

    // All messages of conversation
    $messages = $conversation->messages;
}
```

Comment: Is `user_id` in `conversations` the person who initiated the conversation?

Comment: This doesn't find all the conversations where you are being the recipient?

Comment: I struggled with data modelisation of a private messaging system laravel way this helped a lot even if it's not very recent, Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Your Message table should look like this:

```
MessageID         PK
ConversationID    FK
UserID            FK
ReplyToMessageID  FK       <--- Track responses
Message           String
```

User1ID and User2ID is an anti-pattern.  What if three users are involved in the conversation?    Or four?

Having your relationships in the Message table preserves your many-to-many information, but keeps relationships between conversations and messages, and users and messages, one to many.

You don't need two user tables, just one.

Comment: Robert, his messages table looks exactly like yours. The change should happen in the conversations table. Consider a Many-to-many relationship with a pivot table between `Conversation` and `User`. conversations: `id`, conversations_users: `conversation_id | user_id`.

Comment: To track responses, wouldn't it be better to have a `ReplyToMessageID` column?