# Private messaging with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to set up a simple private messaging system with laravel. Kind of what we have on forum where you can send a private message to a user.
Following this stackoverflow post -> [Conversation, Many-to-Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031312/conversation-many-to-many-relationship) I got to a point but I think I'm missing something..

I made the tables as suggested in that post and also the methods from the Models. So, exactly the same. 
In order to send a message to a user I'm using this method in my controller (I think the way I'm saving this, might be the problem)

//Routes

```
Route::post('/browse/profile/{id}/message', 'MessageController@store');

Route::get('/profile/messages','MessageController@show')->name('mymessages');
```

//Store method

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'title' => 'required|min:5|max:100',
      'message' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $conversation = new Conversation;
    $message = new Message;
    $userID = $id;

    $conversation->title = $request->input('title');
    $message->user_id = $userID;
    $message->conversation_id = Auth::id();
    $message->message = $request->input('message');

    $message->save();
    $conversation->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Here I'm using a form to get the data and I'm setting the action of the form with jquery. So the $userID is the id of the user that I want to send the message to.

//Show method

```
public function show(Message $message)
{
    $userID = Auth::user()->id;

    $conversations = User::find($userID)->conversations;

    return $conversations;

}
```

As you can see in the show method I'm just returning $conversations and unfortunately something is not working because I'm just getting an empty array..
I feel like I didn't understand properly the way this tables are structured.. Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: Models

//Conversation Model

```
class Conversation extends Model
{
  public function messages()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('Message');
  }

  public function users()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('User');
  }
}
```

//Message Model

```
class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['message','user_id','conversation_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function conversation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Conversation::class);
    }
}
```

// User Model methods

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class);
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class); // not as relevant, because these are all messages across conversations
}
```

//Messages Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('conversation_id');
        $table->text('message');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//Conversation & Conversation Pivot Tables

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('conversation_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('conversation_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');

        $table->primary(['conversation_id','user_id']);
    });
}
```

Comment: show us the model file.

Comment: I edited the post and I included pretty much everything.

Comment: return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Message','id'); this is how I did it on my models. Putting the model's location and 'id' is for what is the common key

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I changed it but I'm still getting the same thing. Empty array when I return $conversations..

Comment: User::find($userID)->conversations; It seems in $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class); Why does it contain Conversation::class? That seems to be the problem

Comment: Well, it's a many to many relationship. So, a user can have many conversations and a conversation can have multiple users.. Is this not how it suppose to be?

Comment: refer here. [MANY-TO-MANY RELATIONSHIP] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698196/laravel-eloquent-many-to-many-to-one)